# need date in idea object when votetotal is 100 points

Tags: trigger

[image]

```
trigger update_date_trigger on Idea(before insert, before update) {
    for (Idea p: Trigger.new) {
        if (p.VoteTotal == 100 && p.Date__c != null) {
            p.Date__c = date.Today();
        }
    }
}
```

in this I didn't get my date when votetotal reach 100.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I didn't get my date when votetotal reach 100

Comment: Seems `p.Date__c != null` logic is not valid here. Check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that Idea triggers aren't executed when an idea is voted on, probably because the field is a roll up summary. Technically votes are part of a separate object called `Vote`, which doesn't support triggers.

[image]

You will probably have to implement this feature by scheduling a class to periodically poll the system for Ideas that meet your criterion and update the Date field accordingly.

Comment: hi martin in that image user promote the idea, when it will reach 100(VoteTotal) need date(Today)

Comment: @Rajesh Unfortunately for this task, when a user clicks promote, the system creates a new entry created for the Vote object, and the related Idea record isn't updated. Your date field isn't getting updated because the trigger never fires.

Comment: any idea how to solve this

Comment: @Rajesh I'd schedule a (batch) apex class to run every night just before midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing condition `p.Date__c != null` in

```
if (p.VoteTotal == 100 && p.Date__c != null) {
            p.Date__c = date.Today();
        }
```

Comment: I tried ishwar, still date not get