# Convert Ideas into Case

Tags: case, ideas

I am working on a POC, where we need to convert the Ideas into a Case. Once an Idea reaches, let us say 100 points ( assuming each person’s vote is 10 points ), the idea should gets converted to a case with a record type of Enhancement.

For the Idea object, as VoteTotal/VoteScore is a rollup summary field, there seems to be no way to detect the change using those points or votes. Only when you save or edit the Idea record, the process builder works. But upvoting or down voting doesn't trigger any change to the Idea record as such, hence Process Builder is not getting called.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality? Any pointers on this will be really helpful.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130757/need-date-in-idea-object-when-votetotal-is-100-points - suggestion is to use scheduled batch job (could run every 15 mins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done directly; triggers nor workflows execute when `VoteTotal` hits a threshold. See [SFDC HELP doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ideas_tips.htm&language=en&type=0)

> To monitor the activity of Ideas, you can:
>
> Create a workflow rule or
>   trigger based on the number of comments an idea receives. You cannot
>   create a workflow rule or trigger based on an idea’s vote total or
>   vote count. You also cannot create a trigger that inserts or deletes a
>   comment when the Idea object is updated.
>
> Create a custom report based
>   on an idea's vote score or number of comments.

So, to get close to your goal,

1. Create a scheduled job (Apex)
2. Have it run every hour (or every 15 mins)
3. Apex code scans all Ideas looking for those whose threshold is > 100 and has no Case
4. Creates Case and xrefs the Case to the Idea

Answer (score 0):

The Process Builder should fire, please do check your criteria again may be there is some error in your criteria.

For example, suppose there is a Roll-Up on Opportunity that counts the number of Opportunity Product, when we add/delete the Opportunity Product then Opportunity is also updated and hence all the Triggers, Workflows, Process Builders are fired.

Alternatively you can code to achieve the functionality.